# jQuery remove all URLs from the text in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some divs which contain URLs. I simply want to remove the URLs and replace them with something else, for example 'No URLs allowed'. I have used the replace method with jQuery, but it only replaces the `http` part of the link. How can I replace the whole URLs?

```js
var text = $('#text1').text();

$('#text2').text(text.replace(/http/g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="text1">This is my div with some http://example.com/ URLs in, I simply want to https://example.com remove all the URLs and replace them with 'no URLs allowed'</div><br>
<div id="text2"></div>
```

Comment: Danger: jQuery 2.x is **no longer supported** even for security issues. Upgrade to a current version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, The best regex will be `/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi`

That's because it will only replace the url, not any text after that.

`'http?:.*(?=\s)','g'` this, on the other hand will remove the entire text after it has found a link.

```js
var linkRegex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi;

var str = "This is my div with some http://example.com/ links in, I simply want to https://example.com remove all the links and replace them with 'no links allowed'";
console.log(str.replace(linkRegex, "No Links Allowed"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex `http.*?\s`

```js
var text = $('#text1').text();

$('#text2').text(text.replace(/http.*?\s/g, 'No URLs allowed '));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="text1">This is my div with some http://example.com/ links in, I simply want to https://example.com remove all the links and replace them with 'no links allowed'</div><br>
<div id="text2"></div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't replace with the text that is needed (No Links Allowed)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following regex: `http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+`

Here is the code:

```js
var globalRegex = RegExp('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+','g');
 
var str = "This is my div with some http://example.com/ links in, I simply want to https://example.com remove all the links and replace them with 'no links allowed'";
console.log(str.replace(globalRegex, "No Links Allowed"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood the question before. Here is the edited version

```js
var text = $('#text1').text();

$('#text2').text(text.replace(/(http|https):\/\/([\w\.-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}([\/\w\.\-\_\?\=\!\#,\&amp;]+)/gi, 'no links allowed'));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="text1">This is my div with some http://example.com/ links in, I simply want to https://example.com remove all the links and replace them with 'no links allowed'</div><br>
<div id="text2"></div>
```

Comment: But how to detect there is links?

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```html
<body>    
    <div id="text1">This is my div with some http://example.com/ links in, I simply want to https://example.com remove all
        the links and replace them with 'no links allowed'</div><br>
    <div id="text2"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#text1').each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '"no links allowed"'));
        });
       
    </script>    
</body>
```

Edit

Here is exactly what you need.

```html
$('#text1').each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, ''));
            $('#text2').text('no links allowed');
});
```

Comment: Why would anyone down vote an answer without giving a reason?